# Elementary tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $G,H$ be $R$-modules, and $G \otimes H$ be it's tensor product.

I can't prove it and I suspect it's false that any element $\tau \in G \otimes H$ can be written as $\tau = g \otimes h$ for some $(g,h) \in G \times H$.

But I can't come up with any example of an element that can't be written as an elementary tensor. Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: Hopefully that's enough of a hint. If not let me know and I'll give you another push.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $G=\Bbb Z[x], H= \Bbb R$ treated as $\Bbb Z$-modules. Then for everything to be an elementary tensor would mean that every polynomial in $\Bbb R[x]\cong\Bbb Z[x]\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb R$ is of the form $r\cdot p(x)$ for some $r\in\Bbb R$ and $p(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very low dimensional example: consider a two dimensional vector space $V$ with basis $\left\{v_1,v_2\right\}$. Then $\left\{v_1\otimes v_1, v_2\otimes v_1,v_1\otimes v_2, v_2\otimes v_2\right\}$ is a basis of $V\otimes V$. You can easily show that $$v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1\neq u\otimes w$$
for all $u,w\in V$.

Edit: Be sure to work out the other answer as well, it's a nice example as well.

Comment: My try: Let $V \otimes V = X/T$ (from the construction of the tensor product). Let $\delta_x= y \mapsto \delta_{xy}$Then we have $$v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1 = \delta_{(v_1, v2)} + T + \delta_{(v_2, v_1)} + T =  \delta_{(v_1, v2)} + \delta_{(v_2, v_1)} + T$$. Now, for any $(s,t) \in V^2$ we have $s \otimes t = \delta_{(s, t)} + T$ which is clearly different. Is my proof correct? Can one prove it in a less complex manner?

Comment: There is a very elementary and easy way. Suppose there were such a $u$ and $w$, then $u=av_1+bv_2$ and $w=cv_1+dv_2$ for some $a,b,c,d\in k$ (here $V$ is a $k$-vector space). Plug this in the equation and find some contradiction. (Try it)

Also I'm not completely sure of your notation, what exactly do you mean by this $\delta$ map?

Comment: Yep, it follows that $ac = bd = 0, ad = bc = 1$, which is clearly contradictory in a field, or basically any integral domain.

Comment: In the construction of the tensor product we use the following notation: $X = \langle G_1 \times G_2 \rangle_{\Bbb Z}$, which basically the set of all finite-support maps $G_1 \times G_2 \rightarrow \Bbb Z$. Then all maps $\lbrace\delta_x\rbrace_{x \in G_1 \times G_2}$ form a basis of the module

Comment: Correct. Also your reasoning in the above seems incomplete, why can't  $\delta_{(s,t)}= \delta_{(v_1,v_2)}+\delta_{(v_2,v_1)}$ for some $s,t\in V$? Notice that you just calculated why that's not possible.

Comment: Because on the left side, exactly one element maps to 1 - $(s,t)$, and on the right side - exactly two elements map to 1 - $(v_1, v_2)$ and $(v_2, v_1)$. Hence the maps cannot be equal

Comment: $ac=bd=0$, $ad=bc=1$ is contradictory even in a module over an arbitrary ring, because the product of the first two gives $abcd=0$, and the product of the second two gives $abcd=1$.